# Cumulative sum on grouped objects

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  

conditions = [
    (df['Opened'] <'2022-09-30') & (df['Opened'] > '2022-03-31'),
    (df['Opened'] <'2022-03-31') & (df['Opened'] > '2021-10-31'),
    (df['Opened'] <'2021-10-31') & (df['Opened'] > '2021-04-30'),
    (df['Opened'] <'2021-04-30') & (df['Opened'] > '2020-11-30')]
choices = ['Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3','Group4']
df['Group'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='None')
df['SentMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Sent']).dt.to_period('M')
```

[image]

I would like to get a cumulative sum of the amount column, but for specific groupings - by Tranche and month Opened. I tried:

```
df=df.groupby(['Tranche','Opened','SentMonth','ID'],as_index=False).sum('Amount')
df.groupby(['SentMonth','Tranche','Opened']).sum('Amount')
test=df[df.Opened=='2021-12-29'].groupby(['Tranche','Opened','SentMonth','ID'],as_index=False).sum('Amount')
test['cumulative']=test.groupby(['SentMonth','Tranche','Opened'])['Amount'].cumsum(axis=0)
test
```

If I take Tim and Tom as an example, I would like to group them because they have the same month opened and they are both in the red tranche. So in the table below I do want red 2022-01 to be 30, because it's the sum of Tim's amount and Tom's amount, and the total should be the sum of their totals. But the Red 2022-02 row should be 40/160 and is coming up as 10/100.

Thanks for any suggestions! :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding 'agg' method like:

```py
df=df.groupby('SentMonth').agg('Amount': 'count')
```

Comment: This gives me an invalid syntax error, as does aggregate('Amount': 'count') and agg('Amount':['count'])